# What is the full path for the pkill command?

Tags: files, command, executable

I'm trying to add pkill to my sudoers file, but I think I need the full path for it to not give a syntax error. Does anybody know how to find it?

Comment: Found this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/520072/run-pkill-without-sudo-permission It's located in /usr/bin :D

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Comment: The other option is to use 'whereis pkill'. 'whereis - locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic way to find where a command comes from, if your shell
supports it (bash does), is the `type` built-in. For example:

```
$ type pkill
pkill is /usr/bin/pkill
```

For non-commands, it may print different things, for example:

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```